# компьютер, грамота

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать? Курсы компьютера, курсы компьютерной грамотности или курсы компьютерной грамоты? Кроме "компьютерные курсы".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно: **курсы компьютерной грамотности**.

**ГРАМОТА**,  1. Умение читать и писать. Выучиться грамоте. 2. Официальный документ, устанавливающий или удостоверяющий что-л. 3. Устар. Письмо, послание, записка.

**ГРАМОТНЫЙ**,  1. Умеющий читать и писать; умеющий писать грамотно, без ошибок. **2. Обладающий необходимыми знаниями, сведениями в какой-л. области; знающий.** Г. инженер.  **Грамотность**.

**Компьютерная грамота:** сочетание не соответствует значению слова "грамота" согласно словарю, но может иметь переносное значение, стиль разговорный.

**Курсы компьютера**: значение сочетания неясно, так как родительный падеж может относиться к субъекту или объекту действия (сравнить: чтение книги, чтение автора). Кроме того, речь идет только об умении грамотно пользоваться компьютером, то есть это ограниченная область знания о компьютерах.